# Full Calendar color/textColor not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar with server-side processing.

### PHP

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $event_array = array();

  $event_array['id'] = $row['id'];
  $event_array['title'] = $row['forename'] "" $row['surname'];
  $event_array['start'] = $row['start'];
  $event_array['end'] = $row['end'];
  $event_array['allDay'] = true;
  $event_array['color'] = $row['colour'];
  $event_array['textColor'] = "white";

  array_push($return_array, $event_array);
}
```

### Problem

The `color` and `textColor` values are not having an effect on the calendar. I have read http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/ and these are both valid options but I am not sure if I am using them correctly in the array.

`$row['colour']` is the row in the database storing the colour value such as `black`.

Comment: look at the fullcalender link color and textColor add after the event array not in every event array

Comment: @ankurbhadania I need it per event.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441695/jquery-full-calendar-and-dynamic-event-colors

Comment: or you can try to add "className" http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

I used `$event_array['className'] = $row['colour'];` where `row['colour']` returned for example `black`.

I then used:

```
.black div {
  background-color: black;
  border-color:     black;
  color:            white;
}
```

in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

use like this.

```
    eventRender: function(info) {
        if (moment(info.event.end) < moment()){
            info.el.style.backgroundColor  = "#e3e3e3";
            info.el.style.borderColor ="#e3e3e3";
        } else {
            info.el.style.backgroundColor  = "#6a49fc";
            info.el.style.borderColor ="#6a49fc";
            info.el.style.color = "#ffffff";
          }
      },
```