# Using event.className to change event color for ui-calendar

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, calendar, angular-ui

I am new to ui-calendar and am having some issues setting the event's className property in my code based upon a condition. I haven't been able to find may examples using className like this, but here is what I attempted in my project:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {

    if (event.HighPriority == 1) {
       event.className ='highPriority';
    }

},
```

In my css file I have:

```
.highPriority{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

This line "`event.className ='highPriority';`" does not work. Has anyone done something similar with angular ui-calendar? Any help on the matter would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue with ui-calendar on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/176#event-190991313). Between this comment from vaHuntsMan:

> eventRender is a callback. So you are changing the classname probably
>   too late. Try adding className when you create the event, before
>   adding it to the source array.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441695/jquery-full-calendar-and-dynamic-event-colors) Stack Overflow post, I was able to get my CSS coloring properly.

ui-calendar setup:

```
 events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                ...
                $http.get(url).success(function (result) {
                    $scope.myEvents = result.value;

                        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myEvents.length; i++) {
                              ...
                            if ($scope.myEvents[i].HighPriority) { 
                                $scope.myEvents[i].className = ['highPriority'];
                            }
                        }
                        callback($scope.myEvents);
                })
            },
```

CSS:

```
  .highPriority,
  .highPriority div,
  .highPriority span {
    background-color: red; /* background color */
    border-color: white;     /* border color */
    color: white;           /* text color */
  }
```